# Limit of the joint cdf

Tags: probability

How to see that given a joint cdf $F(x,y)$, we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x,y)=F(y)$ and $\lim_{y\to\infty}=F(x)$ where $F(y)$ and $F(x)$ are marginal cdfs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition we have $F(x,y)=P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)$ for some random vector $(X,Y)$. For $y$ fixed, we have that $x\mapsto F(x,y)$ is increasing and hence
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty} F(n,y),
$$
where $n$ runs through the natural numbers. By continuity of the probability measure we have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}F(n,y)=\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X\leq n,Y\leq y)=P(X<\infty,Y\leq y)=P(Y\leq y)=F(y)
$$
To see why $P(X<\infty,Y\leq y)=P(Y\leq y)$, we must remember that $P(X<\infty,Y\leq y)$ is shorthand notation for $P(\{X<\infty\}\cap\{Y\leq y\})$. Since $X$ is a random variable we know that it only takes on finite values and hence $\{X<\infty\}=\{\omega:X(\omega)<\infty\}=\Omega$, and we conclude that
$$
P(\{X<\infty\}\cap\{Y\leq y\})=P(\Omega\cap\{Y\leq y\})=P(Y\leq y).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I still don't get why $P((-\infty,+\infty)\times(-\infty,y]) = P((-\infty,y])$

Comment: @Kasablanca: See the edit. Remember that $P$ is a probability measure on your underlying probability space $\Omega$, and therefore $P((-\infty,y])$ does not make sense.

Comment: So it's $P^X((-\infty,y])$ that makes sense?

Comment: @Kasablanca: Yes that makes sense. It is shorthand notation for $P(X\leq y)$ or $P(X\in (-\infty,y])$.

Comment: Thank you, this discussion was enlightening!

Comment: @Kasablanca: You're welcome!

Comment: @StefanHansen: I can not agree with you, since $P(X≤x,Y≤y)$ is actually $P(\{X\leq x\}\times \{Y \leq y\})$. It's a Cartesian product which is a subset of $R^2$. Be aware that we are talking about something on the *probability space $(R^2,\tilde F,P)$*.

Comment: @Gizak: $\{X\leq x\}\times\{Y\leq y\}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @StefanHansen: In this context, X and Y are defined on the same *sample space*. We could say that X is from $R_X$ and Y is from $R_Y$, $R_X$ and $R_Y$ form a $R^2$, and $\{X\leq x\} \times \{Y\leq y\}$ forms a *two dimensional Borel algebra*. It's the underlying background.

Comment: @StefanHansen: It doesn't make sense if the ($\{X\leq x\},\{Y \leq y\}$) is the intersection of $\{X\leq x\}$ and $\{Y \leq y\}$.

Comment: @Gizak: What is $R_X$, $R_Y$ and $R^2$? And why doesn't it make sense that $P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)$ is shorthand notation for $P(\{X\leq x\}\cap\{Y\leq y\})$ (which it actually _is_)?

Comment: @StefanHansen: They are both $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R^2}$ is the *sample space*, which is two-dimensional. $P$ is the measurement of *events* and each *event* is a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$. So if we use the measurement in $\mathbb{R^2}$ to calculate events of $\mathbb{R}$, it does not make sense. {X≤x}×{Y≤y} is a *event*, which is a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: @Gizak: The sample space need not be $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$. In general, a random variable $X$ is a function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is some probability space. Here $\Omega$ can be any non-empty set. This means that $\{X\leq x\}$, which in fact is the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leq x\}$, is a subset of $\Omega$. Similarly, $\{X\leq x\}\cap\{Y\leq y\}$ is a subset of $\Omega$, but $\{X\leq x\}\times\{Y\leq y\}$ is a subset of $\Omega\times\Omega$ which we _cannot_ measure by $P$. I'm sorry, but something in your understanding is not right.

Comment: @StefanHansen: Thank you so much! I have been thinking why I can not prove marginal cdf and I thought we are working on the new space stemming from $(S,F,P)$. The {X≤x},{Y≤y} should be the intersection of the inverse image of $(-\infty,x] and (-\infty,y]$, then all of this can work out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $F(x,y)=P(X<x,Y<y)$, thus $\lim_{x->\infty}F(x,y)=\lim_{x->\infty}P(X<x,Y<y)=P(Y<y)=F(y)$